# Handle many tasks, many times with Task Parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

This may not be suitable here, please feel free to move, shout or abuse if so.

We currently have a console application that get started by another and passed in an ID of the 'job', this job will have multiple records that need to be processed. A simple explanation of the flow would be;

```
Starts 50 threads

Gets records to be processed.
if records > 0 see what threads are not still busy and send it some information.
if records = 0 update something else and exit.
Get more records.
Loop.
```

Now, I am looking to convert this into a 'polling' service that is continually running and when new records are available, process them. To take what I have and convert this is fairly simple, but the threads stuff is old and probably outdated.

I was looking to refactor most if not all and use Task.Parallel to process the items. However, I am struggling to get a suitable framework for polling and then processing the items and was looking for suggestions on how to achieve this.

Pretty vague I know, but hopefully enough to give some kind of input.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you describe where these records come from? Are they added to a db?

Comment: At present they are List<T>, but yes they come in from a DB ultimately. They are loaded in batches of 1000 and sent of to the thread pools. Once there are none left to process in that batch, we check for more.

Comment: is this talking to sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience and this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) quote:

> More efficient and more scalable use of system resources.
>
> Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been
>   enhanced with algorithms (like hill-climbing) that determine and
>   adjust to the number of threads that maximizes throughput. This makes
>   tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to
>   enable fine-grained parallelism. To complement this, widely-known
>   work-stealing algorithms are employed to provide load-balancing.

You simply shouldn't care about how many tasks is a good number, or how to create a system where you load balance the threading involved.

Simply use:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork());
```

Every time you want to run something asynchronously, it does all the smart job behind the curtain.

Now since you're likely to create tasks in a loop, please **be extra-careful** not to introduce a closure bug many people had (including me), which you can look up **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item)**.

I have a windows service that runs from 1 to 500 Tasks, and never had trouble.

Hope this helps,

Bab.

Comment: 500 Tasks may be okay, but I'm not sure something like 10000 is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are polling for new records in a DB table, a better approach would be to install an INSERT-trigger (and possibly also UPDATE- and DELETE-triggers) on this table and to send a message to your service when a new records is inserted.

See [Posting Message to MSMQ from SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555070/en-us) on MSDN.

Comment: +1 for trigger. If you have a DB, you may as well use its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The "polling service" sounds like a nice case for an observable collection. There's Rx, a nice way to handle them (http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples), which I think uses the TPL.