# Running several EntityFramework database queries in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am trying to run three database queries in parallel but I'm not sure that I am doing it correctly.

I have made three functions which each make a query to the database.

```
private static async Task<string> getAccountCodeAsync(string deviceId)
{
    long deviceIdLong = long.Parse(deviceId);
    using (var db = new NetworksEntities())
    {
        return db.Devices.Where(x => x.DeviceId == deviceIdLong)
            .Select(x => x.AccountCode)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

private static async Task<string> getDeviceTypeAsync(string deviceId)
{
    long deviceIdLong = long.Parse(deviceId);
    using (var db = new NetworksEntities())
    {
        return db.Devices.Where(x => x.DeviceId == deviceIdLong)
            .Select(x => x.DeviceType)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .DeviceType;
    }
}

private static async Task<string> getUserNameAsync(string userId)
{
    int userIdInt;
    Int32.TryParse(userId, out userIdInt);
    using (var db = new NetworksEntities())
    {
        return db.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userIdInt)
            .Select(x => x.Email)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I then in my code I run the three tasks:

```
var TaskAccountCode = await getAccountCodeAsync(deviceId);
var TaskDeviceType = await getDeviceTypeAsync(deviceId);
var TaskUsername = await getUserNameAsync(userId);
await Task.WhenAll();   
// use the results from my three tasks to make a new insert into the db.
```

Is what I am doing actually running my three db queries in parallel?

EDIT:

```
private static async Task<string> getAccountCodeAsync(string deviceId)
{
    long deviceIdLong = long.Parse(deviceId);
    using (var db = new NetworksEntities())
    {               
        return db.Devices.Where(x => x.DeviceId == deviceIdLong)
            .Select(x => x.AccountCode)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: No they run synchronously if you call them like that. using await it will run first method, then the second one...etc. To run them in parallel do it like this:  Task.WhenAll(TaskAccountCode, TaskDeviceType,TaskUsername) and remove await.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will have to change the last part of the code to make it run in parallel:

```
var taskAccountCode = getAccountCodeAsync(deviceId);
var taskDeviceType = getDeviceTypeAsync(deviceId);
var taskUsername = getUserNameAsync(userId);
await Task.WhenAll(taskAccountCode, taskDeviceType, taskUsername);
var accountCode = taskAccountCode.Result;
var deviceType = taskDeviceType.Result;
var username  = taskUsername.Result;
```

Notice that there is only one `await`. In your original code you `await` every task one after the other making them run in sequence instead of in parallel.

Also, the methods `getAccountCodeAsync` etc. are not really async methods (you should get a compiler warning about this). However, Entity Framework 6 has support for async operations and to use that you should replace `FirstOrDefault` with [`FirstOrDefaultAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220208%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). For each parallel operation you will have to use a separate context, and that is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Do I have to specify the tasks names in the `Task.WhenAll();` ?

Comment: Youa re correct, I do get compiler warnings on the async methods, but there is no async for reading, I know there is a async for savechanges. And will this run each task on its own thread?

Comment: @Zapnologica: _Do I have to specify the tasks names in the Task.WhenAll(); ?_ Yes you have to.

Comment: I tried changing to firstOrDefaultAsync() but my compiler didn't like it.

Comment: @Zapnologica: Aside from the casing error which I assume isn't the issue you need to use Entity Framework 6. Otherwise you will have to start your own tasks using something like `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Currently using EF 6.1.0 and there is no FirstOrDefaultAsync() , the only thing I can find is the method `FindAsync()` Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Zapnologica: Provided that type type of `NetworkEntities.Devices` is `DbSet<T>` (where `T` is replaced by your actual device type) and that you have `using System.Data.Entity` at the top of your C# file you should have access to the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` extension method (I personally verified this in a small project using EF 6.1). The important point is that `Select` returns `IQueryable<string>` and not `IEnumerable<string>` and that the namespace is imported allowing you to use the extension method.

Comment: aah i added the using and it seemed to have worked now, But now my asyn methods want me to return a string and not a task? Should I `return await db.table.forstordefaultasync()`;

Comment: @Zapnologica: `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` returns a task and you want to return that task from your method marked with `async`. You should not await that task except as I described in my answer using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: in my case `db.FSKDevices.Where(x => x.FSKDeviceId == deviceIdLong).Select(x => x.AccountCode).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` wants to return a String. I tis onyl happy unless I await it in the method, or  if I return a string?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but its just not working like you are explaining. Please see my edit, that is the code I currently have. It tell me to return a string, if I do then the async method moans that it has to return a TASK<>

Comment: @Zapnologica: Who _wants to return a string_ and who _moans_? I assume that you are getting compiler errors. `getAccountCodeAsync` return `Task<string>` thus you want `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` to return `Task<string>`. This means that `Select(...)` should return `IQueryable<string>`. If `AccountCode` is a string property your code looks allright. If you get compiler errors you will have to fix them by reading the description. For good measure I repeat: do __not__ `await` in `getAccountCodeAsync` if you want to enable parallel execution.

Answer (score 2):

No they run one after eachother if you call them like that using await foreach method, it will run first method, then the second one...etc. And the last part `await Task.WhenAll()`, you did not supplied the tasks to wait for completion.

To run them in parallel you have to do it like this:

```
var TaskAccountCode = getAccountCodeAsync(deviceId);
var TaskDeviceType = getDeviceTypeAsync(deviceId);
var TaskUsername = getUserNameAsync(userId);
await Task.WhenAll(TaskAccountCode, TaskDeviceType,TaskUsername);
```