# Parallel.ForEach and async-await

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I had such method:

```
public async Task<MyResult> GetResult()
{
    MyResult result = new MyResult();

    foreach(var method in Methods)
    {
        string json = await Process(method);

        result.Prop1 = PopulateProp1(json);
        result.Prop2 = PopulateProp2(json);

    }

    return result;
}
```

Then I decided to use `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
public async Task<MyResult> GetResult()
{
    MyResult result = new MyResult();

    Parallel.ForEach(Methods, async method =>
    {
        string json = await Process(method);    

        result.Prop1 = PopulateProp1(json);
        result.Prop2 = PopulateProp2(json);
    });

    return result;
}
```

But now I've got an error:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

Comment: Where are you getting this error?  I'm assuming it's an exception, does it occur within `GetResult`?

Comment: Is your `Model` actually a View Model and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and is bound to the view?

Comment: No it is not a view model, probably I have to change the name. It is just a simple `class` with a some props

Comment: getting exception on return `return result;`

Comment: Is `GetResult` affecting performance?

Comment: @Peter Ritchie yes it is.

Comment: Another relevant question: [Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda).

Answer (score 88):

`async` doesn't work well with `ForEach`. In particular, your `async` lambda is being converted to an `async void` method. There are a number of [reasons to avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) (as I describe in an MSDN article); one of them is that you can't easily detect when the `async` lambda has completed. ASP.NET will see your code return without completing the `async void` method and (appropriately) throw an exception.

What you probably want to do is process the data *concurrently*, just not in *parallel*. Parallel code should almost never be used on ASP.NET. Here's what the code would look like with asynchronous concurrent processing:

```
public async Task<MyResult> GetResult()
{
  MyResult result = new MyResult();

  var tasks = Methods.Select(method => ProcessAsync(method)).ToArray();
  string[] json = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  result.Prop1 = PopulateProp1(json[0]);
  ...

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you use prallel in ASP.NET?

Comment: @DirkBoer: Parallel code will dramatically reduce ASP.NET scalability, and interfere with its thread pool heuristics. It is only useful if you have parallelizable CPU-bound work to do and know for certain that you will only have a small number of concurrent users.

Comment: I got the exact same exception as the OP and though there appeared to be a minor improvement in the response for a single user when using Parallel, I can see how it (Parallel.ForEach) may hit us unexpectedly in a live application

Comment: @StephenCleary i've seen your comments around SO on using Parallel code on the server. What do you consider a small number of users exactly or do you have any further reading on this statement? I'm working on a WCF service but curious if this applies to me

Comment: @Dude0001: It depends on a ton of factors - the only way to know for your situation is to run load tests. Simple rule of thumb: if you don't need to, then don't. "Fast enough" is fast enough.

Comment: If I have a large number of items to process, will this code not try to start all of them at the same time, requiring hundreds of threads? I imaging that limiting the level of multi-threading to something around the number of CPU cores would make things faster than trying to do everything at the same time, causing massive task switching overhead.

Comment: @ygoe: "will this code try to start all of them at the same time" Yes. "requiring hundreds of threads?" [No](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: IMHO `Parallel.ForEach` has a lot more advantages compared to using raw tasks. How about wrapping the `Parallel.ForEach` in a task? This will allow the use of `async` while getting the full benefits of using `Parallel.ForEach`. Something like: `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Parallel.ForEach<Item>(items, item => DoSomething(item)));`

Comment: @GETah: `Parallel` has advantages *for parallel processing*. It doesn't work as well for asynchronous work items. Using `Task.Run(() => Parallel...)` is a great pattern for pushing parallel work off a UI thread. You wouldn't want to use it on ASP.NET, though.

Comment: @StephenCleary, OP did not say anything about ASP.net.  What about combining async & parallelism in a worker process?

Comment: @Sean The OP posted the error `An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.`, which only happens on ASP.NET. Combining async and parallelism in a worker process is fine.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Can I ask a question? What do you think about downloading many URLs, where much of the download task involves waiting? I'd like to download several URLs at a time. I thought Parallel might be the answer but it didn't like that my action method was awaitable. Any chance you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: @JonathanWood: You can't use `Parallel` for asynchronous code; you'd want to use asynchronous concurrency, e.g., `Task.WhenAll`. There are lots of answers on SO about that approach.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Okay, thanks. I've been searching around. But I wasn't really sure which direction I should go. I'll look into `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I was running Parallel.ForEach but my code running inside would execute, but the program would continue and exit prematurely (me not knowing parallelism) but your answer of creating multiple tasks and using .WhenAll gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, this was a lifesaver for the client project I'm working on!

Comment: @jmath412: Sounds like an `async` problem; `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with `async`. The new `Parallel.ForEachAsync` does, or `Task.WhenAll` should also work.

Answer (score 23):

.NET 6 finally added [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), a way to schedule asynchronous work that allows you to control the degree of parallelism:

```
var urlsToDownload = new [] 
{
    "https://dotnet.microsoft.com",
    "https://www.microsoft.com",
    "https://twitter.com/shahabfar"
};

var client = new HttpClient();

var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urlsToDownload, options, async (url, token) =>
{
    var targetPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "http_cache", url);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(url, token);
    // The request will be canceled in case of an error in another URL.

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using var target = File.OpenWrite(targetPath);

        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(target);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, with the [AsyncEnumerator NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/1.1.0) you can do this:

```
using System.Collections.Async;

public async Task<MyResult> GetResult()
{
    MyResult result = new MyResult();

    await Methods.ParallelForEachAsync(async method =>
    {
        string json = await Process(method);    

        result.Prop1 = PopulateProp1(json);
        result.Prop2 = PopulateProp2(json);
    }, maxDegreeOfParallelism: 10);

    return result;
}
```

where `ParallelForEachAsync` is an extension method.

Answer (score 5):

Ahh, okay.  I think I know what's going on now.  `async method =>` an "async void" which is "fire and forget" (not recommended for anything other than event handlers).  This means the caller cannot know when it is completed...  So, `GetResult` returns while the operation is still running.  Although the technical details of my first answer are incorrect, the result is the same here: that GetResult is returning while the operations started by `ForEach` are still running.  The only thing you could really do is not `await` on `Process` (so that the lambda is no longer `async`) and wait for `Process` to complete each iteration.  But, that will use at least one thread pool thread to do that and thus stress the pool slightly--likely making use of `ForEach` pointless.  I would simply not use Parallel.ForEach...