# Await Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, parallel-processing

I am stuck in a situation where I have to download multiple files from a list of urls. I found `Parallel.ForEach` as a solution and it really works faster than a simple foreach. But this solution is **not waiting** till all downloads are done.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {"url1","url2","url3",... };

public async void downloadSimpleFile(string fileUrl) {
    //download file logic
}

await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(list,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, downloadSimpleFile));
```

I was also tying:

```
public async Task<bool> downloadSimpleFile(string fileUrl) {
    //download file logic
    return true;
}
```

Now how can I use `downloadSimpleFile` in `Parallel.ForEach`, because up mentioned code is not working anymore?

I was reading some posts about async-await in `Parallel` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137393/parallel-foreach-and-async-await) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallell-foreach) but I'm not getting the idea. Any ideas are apreciated.

Comment: It works faster *because* it's not waiting.  As it says in the questions you link to, you probably don't want to do this.  Just create all the tasks and use `Task.WhenAll` to await completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**Task.WhenAll**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Following code should work:

```
public async Task<bool> downloadSimpleFile(string fileUrl)
{
    //download file logic
    return true;
}

public async Task ProcessList()
{
    var list = new List<string> {"url1", "url2", "url3" };
    var downloadFiles = list.Select(downloadSimpleFile).ToArray();

    var result = await Task.WhenAll(downloadFiles);
}
```

Comment: I tested this method and looks like tasks are started not in parallel at the same time, there is a difference about 0.2 sec in each `downloadSimpleFile` call