# Is there any possible to pause and resume a Parallel.ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

How to  pause and resume the parallel for each based on number of thread executed.

My requirement is I have a N time of loop count in each iteration I have request one API call .the max number of request is 2. i have to wait for any one the request is finished then i have to iterate next one. Please suggest how to pause and resume the parallel foreach loop

My code below,

```
var MaxConcurrency = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };

Parallel.ForEach(ListofWI, MaxConcurrency, async (CurrentWI) =>
{
    ServiceInput objServiceInput = new ServiceInput { Login = newLoginDetails,
        Connectioninfo = newConnectionInfo, WorkItem = CurrentWI.Value,
        Services = mlserviceList };

    String Inputstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objServiceInput,
        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    WIuploader newUpload = new WIuploader(logininfo, CurrentWI.Value, newConnectionInfo);
    Progress<WorkItem> report = new Progress<WorkItem>(workItemUpdate =>
    {
    });
    workItem = await threadingtask.Task.Run(() => newUpload.Execute(report));
    StatusofWorkitem.Add(workItem);
});
```

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` method does not support `async` delegates. See this question: [Parallel.ForEach and async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137393/parallel-foreach-and-async-await).

Comment: Use an `ActionBlock<T>` instead?

Comment: I think you are already doing it, by setting: MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2. This means you will only have max two parallel threads executing your requests at the same time. There is also no need to do: threadingtask.Task.Run as it is practically Parallel.foreach is for. Just execute your newUpload.Execute(report) without wrapping it into a async task.