# Executing RestApi httpclient in parallel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Before you go and close this question  answer provided here
[Parallel HTTP requests using System.Net.Http.HttpCliente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140570/parallel-http-requests-using-system-net-http-httpclient)
does NOT answer my question at all.

I have the following scenario I want to execute the following RestApi calls in parallel

- GetCountries  (I want to wait for result to come back)
- GetSomeOtherData (I dont need to wait but I want to preload in memory for use in next page)
- Get SomethingElse (I dont need to wait but I want to preload in memory for use in next page)

My understanding of "WhenAll" is that it will wait for all to complete and that is not what I need to do.

Using "Task.Run" seems not appropriate as its not "CPU bound" stuff.

So in my head it says "Run them on a different thread" but isnt that what Task.Run does.

How do you handle a situation when you want to execute 3 rest api calls (httpClient) in parallel and you want wait for one and not for the others, the other's result by the time the user goes to the next page , they will be in memory as I will cache them for 1 minute.

**EDITED**

Is there a better way than below , Why did I do this: so that GetSomeOtherData and SomethingElse run at the same time as GetCountries,and they are not waiting/blocking for any to finish.
Somehow it feels wrong but dont know how to improve on this.

```
    _ = Task.Run(async () => { await GetSomeOtherData (); })
    _ = Task.Run(async () => { await SomethingElse  (); })        
    var countries=await GetCountries();
```

Comment: `await GetCountries(); await Task.WhenAll(GetSomeOtherData, SomethingElse);`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary  await Task.WhenAll(GetSomeOtherData, SomethingElse)  means that both method have to finish before I can move on . Correct? what about running them all at the same time in parallel? The only thing I can think of  see my edited answer

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(GetCountries, GetSomeOtherData, SomethingElse);` is all in parallel but that's not what you mention in your post by 'wait for one and not for the others'

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary reply appreciate your time in replying... and may be my post is not clear. GetCountries - I need to wait as It's used immediately the other 2 calls needs  to be called but dont have to block anything and I will cache the results....  what about my edited solution, works but does not seem right -

Comment: *"Task.Run" seems not appropriate as its not "CPU bound"* CPU bound or not isn't relevant. The point is you don't want to wait for it to finish, so you need another thread. Your solution looks fine to me.