# Awaiting tasks from multiple objects

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-core, task, task-parallel-library

I have an application that uses MEF to load plugins. All of these plugins conform to the following interface:

```
public interface IPlugin {
    Task Start();
}
```

All the methods are implemented as `async`: `public async Task Start()`

When the application is running I have an `IEnumerable<IPlugin>` property available with all the plugins. The question is basically how I can run all the `Start()` methods in parallel and wait until all methods are finished?

I know about `Parallel.ForEach(plugins, plugin => plugin.Start())`, but this is not awaitable and execution continues before all plugins are started.

The most promising solution seems to be `Task.WhenAll()`, but I don't know how to send in an unknown list of methods into this without adding some scaffolding (which seems like overhead).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And here's a one-liner:

```
await Task.WhenAll(plugins.Select(p => p.Start()));
```

The plugins will run asynchronously, but not in parallel. If you want for some reason to dispatch plugins to thread pool explicitly, you may add `Task.Run` with `async` lambda into `Select`.

Comment: Son of a bench, it's been staring me in the face this whole time! Would you care to elaborate on "The plugins will run asynchronously, but not in parallel" ?

Comment: You can output `CurrentThread`'s id and you will see that plugins at least start on a single thread. Here's a nice article about it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov For running in parallel, might it not be better to use `AsParallel()` (as in `plugins.AsParallel().Select(p => p.Start())`) instead of `Task.Run`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009181/parallel-foreach-vs-task-factory-startnew).

Comment: @pere57 I doubt it will make any difference. Also I'm not certain that plugins can get any value out of work "chunking" inside parallel query. It should be measured irl, what is better for this case.

Comment: *"The plugins will run asynchronously, but not in parallel."* -- This is not correct. Assuming that the `Start` method returns an incomplete task, in other words that it is truly asynchronous, which is a reasonable assumption to make, the plugins will run concurrently. Multiple asynchronous operations will be in-flight at the same time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, it depends on what you consider "parallel", and, in general, it depends. If there's a single-threaded context, the plugins would run on a single thread interchanged. Even in the answer I didn't mention how to run plugins in parallel (only how to offload them to thread pool explicitly), because nor thread pool usage, nor even manually creating a separate thread for each plugin give any guarantees of parallel execution.

Comment: Sergey what are the assumptions that you've made about the `Task Start();` method? We have no idea about how this method is implemented in the concrete `IPlugin` types. It might be `Task Start() => Task.Factory.StartNew(CpuBoundAction, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`, in which case your statement *"The plugins will not run in parallel."* doesn't hold. The action of each task will be running on a dedicated thread, in parallel with other task's actions. Assuming of course that the program runs on a machine with multiple cores.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, none assumptions whatsoever. The OP asked the question of how to await `IEnumerable<Task>`, and also mentioned the goal of running `Start()` (whatever inside) in parallel. I gave the answer to the first question, mentioning that the second is not guaranteed. If you want I can re-phrase it as "asynchronously, but not necessarily in parallel".
Off-topic: `LongRunning` task also does not guarantee parallel execution, AFAIR, it simply notifies `ThreadPool` that may choose to not spawn a thread (sorry, I don't want to dive into the sources right now).

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var plugin in plugins) 
{
   var task = plugin.Start();
   tasks.Add(task);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: My pet peeve is `if(collection.Count > 0)` - use `if(collection.Any())`.  You don't care how many items, just 'is there any?'.

Comment: @Neil, very good suggestion! I always keep forgetting that `Any()` is more efficient in this case. :)

Comment: Or you can ommit `Any` check as `WhenAll` can work with zero tasks.

Comment: Also you probably meant `Task.WhenAll`, not `Tasks.WhenAll`

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov, I didn't know you could pass an empty collection to it, so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Microsoft's Reactive Framework to ensure that this is awaitable, happens asynchronously and in parallel.

```
await
    plugins
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(plugin => Observable.FromAsync(() => plugin.Start()))
        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `Start` method returns a `Task`. I would define a list of plugin loading tasks and check with `Task.WhenAll` when every task is completed. After that you can assume all `Start` methods have returned.

```
List<IPlugin> plugins = ... 
var pluginsLoadingTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(var plugin in plugins)
{
    pluginsLoadingTasks.Add(plugin.Start());
}

// It's not necessary to check if pluginsLoadingTasks is empty, 
// because WhenAll won't throw an exception in that case
await Task.WhenAll(pluginsLoadingTasks);
// You can assume all Start methods have completed
```

I suggest you [to read the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall) between `Task.WhenAll` and `Parallel.ForEach` constructs.

Comment: How is your answer different from what Frank suggested?