# Parallel.ForEach or Task.WhenAll when involving async operations?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, parallel.foreach

I've read the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall) closely related thread, but I'd like to ask about a more specific thing.

If we need to run Tasks/methods asynchronously, and those tasks themselves run other tasks/await other tasks, which variant is preferred - `Parallel.ForEach`, or `Task.WhenAll`? I will demonstrate with some code below:

```
public async Task SomeWorker(string param1, HttpClient client,
    List<FillMeUp> emptyCollection)
{
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    message.Headers.Add("someParam", param1);
    message.RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.somesite.me");
    var requestResponse = await client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var content = await requestResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    emptyCollection.Add(new FillMeUp()
    {
        Param1 = param1
    });
}
```

Used with `WhenAll`:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    List<FullCollection> fullCollection = GetMyFullCollection();
    List<FillMeUp> emptyCollection = new List<FillMeUp>();
    List<Task> workers = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fullCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        workers.Add(SomeWorker(fullCollection[i].SomeParam, client,
            emptyCollection));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(workers).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Do something below with already completed tasks
}
```

Or, all of the above written in a `Parallel.ForEach()`:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    List<FullCollection> fullCollection = GetMyFullCollection();
    List<FillMeUp> emptyCollection = new List<FillMeUp>();
    Parallel.ForEach<FullCollection>(fullCollection, (fullObject) =>
    {
       HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
       message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
       message.Headers.Add("someParam", fullObject.SomeParam);
       message.RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.somesite.me");
       var requestResponse = client.SendAsync(message)
           .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       var content = requestResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
           .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       emptyCollection.Add(new FillMeUp()
       {
          Param1 = fullObject.SomeParam
       });
    });
}
```

I'm aware that Lists are not thread safe. It's just something to demonstrate the nature of my question.

Both methods of `HttpClient` (`SendAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync`) are asynchronous, and as such must be called synchronously in order to work with `Parallel.ForEach`.

Is that preferred over the `Task.WhenAll` route? I've tried various performance tests, and I can't seem to find a difference.

Comment: The fact you had to write `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` inside `Parallel.ForEach` shows it's not meant for async operations. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, ie processing large amounts of data, eg an array with 1M items.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, those should definitely be used in an async method, thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the main consideration here is performance. (It always is :-) but read on - using the correct construct in the correct case will guarantee you the best performance)

Think of `Parallel.ForEach` as a special `ForEach` which is parallelizing the individual (synchronous) tasks. While you could shove already asynchronous operations in it (by blocking), it seems contrived and misused - you will lose the async/await benefits of each tasks by doing so. The only "benefit" that you get out of it is that its behavior from the stand point of view of your code flow is synchronous - it will not complete until all threads it spawned return.

Since your individual tasks are already async, it is the latest feature of the `Parallel.ForEach` that `Task.WhenAll` gives you.

Answer (score 8):

In general you need the `Parallel` class when you have loads of work for your CPU to do. You need the `Task` class when you have to wait for loads of work that the external world will do for you.

- [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) = Calculations. ([CPU-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean))
- [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) = Waiting for web servers, file systems and databases to respond. (I/O-bound)

Starting from .NET 6, the `Parallel` is now equipped with with the asynchronous [`ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method, which accepts an asynchronous `body` delegate, and supports the same options as the synchronous `Parallel` methods. The most important option is the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), because web servers, file systems and databases all perform miserably when overflowed by requests. Prior to this we had to resort to advanced tools like the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library, or write custom `ForEachAsync` implementations as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations).

It should be noted that `Task`s can also be used for CPU-bound work. The `Parallel` class uses `Task`s internally as building blocks. This relationship is apparent by the umbrella term [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) (TPL).