# How to run 50 threads together from a list which calls the same method in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

I have a `list` which has `100,000` records.
I want to iterate throught the `list` and call a method in C#.
I want to run the method in `50` threads inside the list in order to *increase performance*.

I checked the option of `Parallel.Foreach`.

but not able to set how many threads should run

Comment: You cannot increase compute-bound performance by using using more threads than you have processor cores. Use `Parallel.ForEach()` and let *it* decide how many threads to use.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code, please? Often an optimization matters more than executing in parallel.

Comment: Hi , I am calling a web service for each record in a list

Comment: So your workload is I/O bound, not CPU bound. In this case forget about the `Parallel` class and go with the `Task` class. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272848/parallel-foreach-or-task-whenall-when-involving-async-operations/58274118#58274118) for a bit more details.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can specify `50` threads in `Parallel.ForEach`, e.g.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(
    list,
    new ParallelOptions() {
      MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 // we want 50 threads
    },
    item => {
      //TODO: your code here
    });
```

However, increasing number of threads (without increasing number of **CPU cores**) will not bring better performance.