# PLINQ vs Sync Over Async: what is the difference?

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel-processing, plinq

I love PLINQ.  In all of my test cases on various parallelization patterns, it performs well and consistently.  But I recently ran into a question that has me a little bothered: what is the functional difference between these two examples?  What, hopefully if anything, qualifies the PLINQ example to not be similar or equivalent to the following anti-pattern?

PLINQ:

```
public int PLINQSum()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, N)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select((x) => x + 1)
        .Sum();
}
```

Sync over async:

```
public int AsyncSum()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, N)
        .Select((x) => Task.Run(() => x + 1));

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.Sum();
}
```

Comment: One observed difference in behavior: in my tests, where N is the number of operations to complete, and M is the size of the operations, as N increases and M decreases, PLINQ remains at or below synchronous runtime, whereas the async example above skyrockets to several orders of magnitude slower than the synchronous test.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103047/8126362). It discusses the difference between `Parallel.ForEach` vs `Task.Run` within `foreach`, but this equally applies to PLINQ.

Comment: The other difference in your case is that as soon as you nest `Task.Run` in a `Select`, you are then working with `Task<int>` objects and not `int` values, so you cannot easily chain additional PLINQ operations (e.g. `Where`) without waiting for those tasks to complete.

Answer (score 3):

The `AsyncSum` method is not an example of [Sync over Async](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). It is an example of using the `Task.Run` method with the intention of parallelizing a calculation. You might think that `Task` = async, but it's not. The `Task` class was introduced with the .NET Framework 4.0 in 2010, as part of the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), [two years before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) the advent of the async/await technology with the  .NET Framework 4.5 in 2012.

**What is Sync over Async:** We use this term to describe a situation where an asynchronous API is invoked and then waited synchronously, causing a thread to be blocked until the completion of the asynchronous operation. It is implied that the asynchronous API has a truly asynchronous implementation, meaning that it uses [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) while the operation is in-flight. Most, [but not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-c-sharp-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-ui-thread), of the asynchronous APIs that are built-in the .NET platform have truly asynchronous implementations.

The two examples in your question are technically different, but not because one of them is Sync over Async. None of them is. Both are parallelizing a synchronous operation (the mathematical addition `x + 1`), that cannot be performed without utilizing the CPU. And when we use the CPU, we use a thread.

Characterizing the `AsyncSum` method as anti-pattern might be fair, but not because it is Sync over Async. You might want to call it anti-pattern because:

1. It allocates and schedules a `Task` for each number in the sequence, incurring a gigantic overhead compared to the tiny computational work that has to be performed.
2. It saturates the `ThreadPool` for the whole duration of the parallel operation.
3. It forces the `ThreadPool` to create additional threads, resulting in oversubscription (more threads than CPUs). This results in the operating system having more work to do (switching between threads).
4. It has bad behavior in case of exceptions. Instead of stopping the operation as soon as possible after an error has occurred, it will invoke the lambda invariably for all elements in the sequence. As a result you'll have to wait for longer until you observe the error, and finally you might observe a huge number of errors.
5. It doesn't utilize the current thread. The current thread is blocked doing nothing, while all the work is done by `ThreadPool` threads. In comparison the PLINQ utilizes the current thread as one of its worker threads. This is something that you could also do manually, by creating some of the tasks with the `Task` constructor (instead of `Task.Run`), and then use the [`RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously) method in order to run them on the current thread, while the rest of the tasks are scheduled on the `ThreadPool`.

```
var task1 = new Task<int>(() => 1 + 1); // Cold task
var task2 = Task.Run(() => 2 + 2); // Hot task scheduled on the ThreadPool
task1.RunSynchronously(); // Run the cold task on the current thread
int sum = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Result.Sum(); // Wait both tasks
```

The name `AsyncSum` itself is inappropriate, since there is nothing asynchronous happening inside this method. A better name could be `WhenAll_TaskRun_Sum`.

Comment: While I agree with some of your assessment here, according to the Microsoft documentation on Task.Run, the action passed to the method is the action to be executed "asynchronously", sans the "async" keyword,  The best definition of the sync over async anti-pattern is "when you’re using a blocking wait on an async method, instead of awaiting the results asynchronously.  This wastes the thread, causes unresponsiveness (if called from the UI), and exposes you to potential deadlocks." https://makolyte.com/fixing-the-sync-over-async-antipattern

Comment: Although, you're right that PLINQ is apparently re-using the originating thread via under-the-hood optimization, and this isn't occurring in the latter example.

Comment: @RTD you are right that the docs describe the `Task.Run` `action` parameter as *"The work to execute asynchronously"*. But if you see the docs for the `Thread` constructor, it says: `start`: *"A delegate that represents the methods to be invoked when this thread begins executing"*. My point is that the term "asynchronous" is used selectively in the docs, even for APIs that do similar things. Both the `Task.Run(action)` and the `new Thread(action).Start()` invoke an action on another thread. Would you say that starting a thread is an asynchronous operation? Or that it's an anti-pattern?

Comment: My understanding is that there is some overlap between "async" and "parallel", but they are not equivalent as an asynchronous task may or may not be scheduled for the originating thread, depending on the task scheduler, if it is a background thread from the threadpool.  In the provided example that might not be the case, it can be a foreground thread in, say, a console application, but if for some unfortunate reason it were ASP.Net servicing a request, it would be from the threadpool, so it becomes sync over async, blocking a worker thread from re-use.