# ArgumentOutOfRangeException Using Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I'm getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when I'm really not sure why.

```
Task[] downloadTasks = new Task[music.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < music.Count; i++)
    downloadTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadAudio(music[i], lstQueue.Items[i]));
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(downloadTasks, (tasks) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("All the downloads have completed!",
        "Success",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
});
```

The error occurs when the `for loop` runs when `i = 1` and I'm not sure why it does this when I'm positive that `music.Count = 1`.

I always tried this approach as an alternative to the `for loop` and got the same exception:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (MusicFile song in music)
{
    downloadTasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadAudio(song, lstQueue.Items[index]));
    index++;
}
```

Is there anything in the above code that might cause this?

I'm also not sure if this is relevant, but when I can accomplish the same thing using threads without any exception. It was only when I tried implementing tasks that this exception appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you're passing `StartNew` a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), which implicitly captures your `i` variable. This effect is called [Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net).

In order to get the proper behavior, you'll have to make a local copy of your index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < music.Count; i++)
{
    var currentIndex = i;
    downloadTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                                             DownloadAudio(music[currentIndex],
                                             lstQueue.Items[currentIndex]));
}
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem above, now I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` for trying to access `lstQueue.Items`.

Comment: That's because `lstQueue` is probably a UI object, which you're trying to access from a background thread (and is not permitted). What does it contain?

Comment: It's a `ListView` that hold the progress percentage for a download. I'm trying to update the progress of each download simultaneously. But I'll figure out how to do what I'm trying to. Thank you!

Comment: @Minato Then look into [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In both instances, you are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) `i` in the first example, or your manually assigned `index` in the second.

What is happening is that the final value of `i / index` is used after the loop completion, which is when `i++` has incremented beyond the size of the iterated array. (See [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item))

Either capture the value of i inside the loop with an additional variable as per @Yuval, or alternatively, look at ways of coupling the two collections together, such that you do not need to iterate `music` and `lstQueue` independently, e.g. here we pre-combine the two collections into a new anonymous class:

```
var musicQueueTuples = music.Zip(lstQueue, (m, q) => new {Music = m, QueueItem = q})
    .ToList();

// Which now allows us to use LINQ to project the tasks:
var downloadTasks = musicQueueTuples.Select(
       mqt => Task.Factory.StartNew(
         () => DownloadAudio(mqt.Music, mqt.QueueItem))).ToArray();

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(downloadTasks, (tasks) => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Closures is your problem, where the variable i is being referenced by the lambada expression, thus it has access to i and always reads its value directly from the memory.

You can create a factory function that create task handlers. You can follow the following idea to solve the problem.

```
private Action CreateTaskHandler(int arg1)
{
    return () => DownloadAudio(music[arg1], lstQueue.Items[arg1])
}

Task[] downloadTasks = new Task[music.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < music.Count; i++)
    downloadTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(CreateTaskHandler(i));
}
```