# Is thread safe create a task with a concurrentbag

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a ConcurrentBag collection, and for every item in this, i do a task for do some work.

I know that Parallel.ForEach with ConcurrentBag is thread safe, but i never done  parallelism in this way.

My code looks like this

```
public void Work(IList<MyModel> data)
{
   var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
   var safeData = new ConcurrentBag<MyModel>(data);
   foreach (var item in safeData )
   {
      var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeTask(item));
      tasks.Add(task);
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

So, this code is thread safe?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Maybe this question could be: "item" will be thread safe or could change his value between iterations?

**EDIT 2:**
I refer a if this code  could fall in this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item).

**Edit 3:**
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item), "Wonko the sane" is having a problem when he works directly with a loop variable. I thought that this problem could be corrected using ConcurrentBag, but in some answers, tell me that i don't need ConcurrentBag at all. So:

Is a good idea use directly a loop variable?

When is recomended copy the value to another variable?

Is safe to work directly with a loop variable from ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Which part of this single threaded code you expect to have problems with? (Ignoring part that runs `SomeTask(item)` on separate threads which presumably thread safe).

Comment: Are you asking about closure? Can you provide an explanation of your second wording of question?

Comment: The tasks and safeData collections are used by only *one* thread.  So always thread-safe and no point in using a ConcurrentBag.  The threads party on the data elements, there is no way to tell from the snippet whether those objects are used in a thread-safe way.  Tends to work out well since each thread munches on a distinct element but trouble starts when the elements have an object reference to the same object and a worker thread modifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to existing answer:

The problem isn't about multithreading or concurrency. It's about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

1. It's ok to use directly loop variable if you understand what's going on.
2. In case of `foreach` it depends on your compiler version. If code will be compiled with older versions it will lead to problem, described in [that very question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4684320/3872935). If you use `for` loop, you should always copy loop variable. For more details you can see links in [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684337/3872935).
3. As already mentioned using `ConcurrentBag` will not affect the result.
   It's safe to close over loop variable if you have older version of compiler than `4.0.30319.1` (in case of MS compiler). [More info about compiler versions](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/ItDepends.NET/tree/master/ClosureAndForeach).

Also as mentioned in comments to that question, you can use static analysis tools which will highlight such cases.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `ConcurrentBag` for this code at all.... And you don't even need `ConcurrentBag` for `Parallel.ForEach`. Argument to `Parallel.ForEach` does not need to be thread safe.

Instead you could simply write,

```
public void Work(IList<MyModel> data)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(data, item=>{
       DoSomeTask(item);
   });
}
```

alternatively...

```
public void Work(IList<MyModel> data)
{
   Task.WaitAll(data.Select(item=>{
       DoSomeTask(item);
   }));
}
```

You need `ConcurrentBag` only if you are modifying it within the code that executes inside `DoSomeTask`.

Each `item` is an isolated instance for each task, unless you have duplicate items in the collection. Even if you have duplicate items in the input list, `ConcurrentBag` will not solve anything.