# Different behaviour on parallel Task execution with removing elements from a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, task

I wanted to test parallel adding and removing to a `ConcurrentDictionary`.
I have the following code in my test class:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void T_Parallel_Removing
    {
        var management = new Management();

        List<Task> AddTasks = new List<Task>();
        List<Task> RemoveTasks = new List<Task>();

        var units = new List<Unit>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var unit = new Unit();
            units.Add(unit);
            AddTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AddUnit(management, unit)));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(AddTasks.ToArray());
    }
```

The `AddUnit` and `RemoveUnit` methods:

```
    public void AddUnit(Management m, Unit u,)
    {
        management .AddPlantUnit(u, "",);
    }

    public void RemoveUnit(Management m, Unit u)
    {
        m.RemovePlantUnit(u.Adress);
        Console.WriteLine(u.Adress);
    }
```

This works perfectly fine. But when i start Removing something odd happens (ignore the int areas, I somehow thought that they are a part of the problem, but they are not)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        {
            RemoveTasks .Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[i])));
        }
```

Here i get always the same address and the output if for every task the same.

But if I use following code:

```
         RemoveTakes.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[0])));
         RemoveTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[1])));
         RemoveTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[2])));
         RemoveTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[3])));
         RemoveTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[4])));
         RemoveTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[5])));
```

It works without a problem. If I add some dummy Code or a `Thread.Sleep(1)` into the for loop it also works (every task gets a different address)

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: If you change `Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[i]))` to `Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i))` what is written to the console? Is that what you expected?

Comment: Without knowing about [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428617/1997232) nearly any lambda in the loop = [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16264289/1997232).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
{
  RemoveTakes.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[i])));
}
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

You should change it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
{
  var bob = i;
  RemoveTakes.Add(Task.Run(() => RemoveUnit(management, units[bob])));
}
```

With your original code, by the time the `Task` ran the value of `i` had changed. So you need to store that in a separate variable (`bob` - scoped inside the loop) so that the first `Task` gets `0`, the next gets `1` etc.

Your issue is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item) (although that uses a `foreach` the principle is the same).

**Note that if you have Resharper installed it should have [highlighted](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AccessToModifiedClosure.html) this issue for you.**

Comment: will bob not be destroyed after every run?

Comment: No, `bob` will be kept alive until it is no longer 'needed' (that is how closures work). This, in practice, is when `RemoveUnit` finishes executing.