# Is reassigning a task value necessary when not using task.ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, continuewith

When reading a post, [Starting Tasks In foreach Loop Uses Value of Last Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684320/starting-tasks-in-foreach-loop-uses-value-of-last-item/4684337#4684337)), the marked answer makes a lot of sense.  The author created a new variable, pathCopy, to use in the task.  My question is, is this only necessary when Task.ContinueWith() is used?

Here is an example:

```
    private void GetAuditFiles()
    {
        _auditFiles = new ConcurrentBag<AuditFile>();

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var auditFile in Directory.GetFiles(_properties.AuditFileOutputPath))
        {
            var taskfile = auditFile;

            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var file = DeserializeProcessProperties<AuditFile>(File.ReadAllText(taskfile));
                file.filename = Path.GetFileName(taskfile);
                _auditFiles.Add(file);
            }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
```

Do I need to set a variable like this "var taskfile = auditFile;"?

Note: I am using an updated version of VS 2017 and its C# compiler.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with `ContinueWith`. It does have something to do with the C# 4 compiler and earlier. Are you really using such a compiler in 2018?

Comment: It's necessary whenever you're changing a variable after using it in a closure and you don't want the closure to observe that change.  Whether you're doing that when not using `ContinueWith` is not something we can really say without knowing how you *are* accomplishing that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There are plenty of situations where you end up closing over a variable that changes in any version of C# from 2.0 to present.  Now what can put you into that situation can be slightly different in different versions of the language, but that by no means makes this a C# 2-4 issue exclusively.

Comment: I would also caution that the `ContinueWith` shown in the answer (but just copied from the question) is broken code and shouldn't be copied. Each `ContinueWith` is independently executed with no synchronization and they're all updating a shared variable. You may lose a store which changes it from `true` to `false` due to races.

Comment: @Servy - but for *that* question and answer it very much is the `foreach` behaviour of older versions that the answer was written to address.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever We have no idea what actual code this user is attempting to apply that approach to, and whether or not that code involves mutating a variable after closing over it, because we have no idea what their code looks like at all.

Comment: That question and answer had nothing to do with *Tasks*, much less `ContinueWith`. The actual problem was variable capture by the lambda. The entire code wouldn't be needed in any supported .NET version nowadays - PLINQ could be used to perform all operations in parallel and collect the results, eg with a simple `Min()`: `paths.AsParallel().Select(ProcessPicture).Min();`. If `ProcessPicture` was rewritten as a real async method, it could be `var results=await Task.WhenAll(paths.Select(ProcessPictureAsync));` followed eg by a `var allTrue=results.All(r=>r);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos PLINQ was added in the same version as `Task` was.  It's not any newer.

Comment: @Servy yes, but I was trying to think of ways of rewriting the entire operation at the time. Jon Skeet answered about the closure, not `ContinueWith` anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You implied that your solution is using newer tools.  I'm just saying that the solution you provided was available at the time that answer was posted.

Comment: @Servy - well, we now have the code, and it's entirely about `foreach`. If you hadn't wanted to discuss the only code available previously, you should surely have voted to close but didn't do so.

Comment: To OP - you should surely have read the comments and the links to Eric Lippert's Blog included in the answer that explained why this specific issue was no longer relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [damien-the-unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever), for pointing me back to [Eric Lippert's Blog: closing over the loop variable part two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two/).

So the short answer is yes, if I am c# v 4.0 or earlier.  It is unneeded in any case if at c# 5.0 or later.